# IMDB App has stopped working

Tags: android

I am getting this warning: Unfortunately IMDB has stopped. How do I stop getting this warning? Uninstalling And installing The IMDB App ineffective

Comment: Post your code & logcat

Comment: ha ha, im getting that too. someone better send them an email and let them know. probably some update they had these last few days and gone to crap -- click on report and send them a feedback mail

Comment: i see you raised the issue on imdb -- https://getsatisfaction.com/imdb/topics?topics[type]=problem -- theres nothing you can do at your end. i suggest uninstalling the app until you hear from them